# D3.js - Directed Acyclic Graph : how to rearrange the nodes and edges to avoid intersection of edges

Tags: d3.js, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, webcola, graphdracula

I have to create the nodes and edges, having interconnections. I am using `d3` js for the same. Now the problem is that the graphs look so much messy. I tried using quadratic bezier curves to draw the edges between the nodes. I want that If a press a button it should rearrange into simplified view. 
[image: my graph]

I happened to look at metacademy, they are a open source project. Which have the exact functionality I am looking for. https://metacademy.org/graphs/edit/new, you would need to login. However not able to find their part of code which is doing the same.

**Initially created graph**

[image: initial]

**After pressing the refresh button**

[image: after refresh]

I am pretty new to d3js, so I will be thankful for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a pretty old question, but FWIW, I designed the graph you're referring to.

Getting graphs to organize so that it minimizes edge crossing is an area of active research. For metacademy, I integrated d3.js + dagre
https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre